# Fill in missing values in lists

Tags: python

Lets say I have 2 lists of data related to a time stamp and a number so:

```
list1 = ['00:00:02', '00:00:05', '00:00:06']
list2 = [2,3,4]
```

I want to essentially fill in the missing time stamps to the rest of the day and have a '0' for any time there is not a coreseponding number to the time stamp, assuming the times match the number sin list1 and list2.  So we get:

```
list1 = ['00:00:02', '00:00:05', '00:00:06']
list2 = [2,3,4]

list3 = ['00:00:00', '00:00:01', '00:00:02', '00:00:03', '00:00:04', '00:00:05', '00:00:06']
list4 = [0,0,2,0,0,3,4]
```

Been trying to conceptualize how to do this any can't think of anything logical.

Comment: So you just want to define the range by `min(list2)`, `max(list2)` and create a time for such a range?

Comment: @What yes its a range of seconds in the day and values that math each.  When there is no value corresponding to list1 it will add a 0 instead

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having hard-coded lists you could have a generator to yield each pair:

```
from functools import reduce

def base60(ts):
    """Parses the timestamps HH:MM:SS into monotonic integer numbers"""
    return reduce(lambda acc, v: acc * 60 + int(v), ts.split(":"), 0) 

def to_ts(v):
    """Convert a single integer representing a "base 60" HH:MM:SS timestamp into a timestamp sting"""
    parts = []
    while v:
        parts.insert(0, "{:02d}".format(v % 60))
        v //= 60
    return ":".join((["00"] * (3 - len(parts))) + parts)

def timeseries(timestamps, values):
    counter = 0
    for timestamp, value in zip(timestamps, values):
        target = base60(timestamp)
        while counter < target:
            # While internal counter is less than the next
            # timestamp in the given series, 
            # yield the counter and a value of zero. 
            yield to_ts(counter), 0
            counter += 1
        yield timestamp, value
        counter += 1
```

And if you really need the result as two separate static sequences (although zip yields tuples rather than lists):

```
list3, list4 = zip(*timeseries(list1, list2))
```

Comment: Could you maybe add some comments? Just a short description of what each function does would be great.

Comment: check if this suffices.

Comment: That goes a long way in making the code easier to figure out, thanks. Now the reader only has to analyze 1 function instead of 3.

Comment: Very elegant solution +1. The `to_ts` function is a bit broken though, as in `to_ts(2) = '2'` for example. This assumes the timestamps are ordered in the original, which seems to be the case. The unpacking at the end also misses a `*`.

Comment: sorry - fixed those.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this, by putting your data in a `dict`. Credits to Aran-Fey for making this more efficient.

```
import time

list1 = ['00:00:02', '00:00:05', '00:00:06']
list2 = [2,3,6]

def get_sec(time_str):
    h, m, s = time_str.split(':')
    return int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + int(s)

timestamps = dict(zip(list1, list2))
list3 = []
list4 = []

for t in range(get_sec(list1[-1])+1):
    time_str = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(t))
    num = timestamps.get(time_str, 0)

    list3.append(time_str)
    list4.append(num)

print(list3, list4)
```

Comment: Not sure what you're planning, but I think an OrderedDict does more harm than good here. Why don't you just use a set instead of a dict and have the loop append its results to a list? Then you wouldn't need to sort anything.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I don't get it. My point was to create key value pairs. With a set of tuples I get the order but I can't figure out how to test if the key is in the set.

Comment: You're right, the set was a bad idea. But more importantly, the code is much cleaner if you only use the dict for lookup, and not as the output. Isn't [this](http://dpaste.com/0VW12HZ) more readable _and_ efficient? (You can use that code btw, I don't mind)

Answer (score 0):

You can map the timestamps in `list1` to the existing values in `list2`. Then, find the maximum timestamp in the input and use the result to create the full range of new timestamps. By using the original mapping, you can iterate over the range, create the timestamp for the current value at iteration, and attempt to access the corresponding value in the dictionary. By using `dict.get`, the filler value can be applied should the generated timestamp not exist in the original input:

```
import re
list1 = ['00:00:02', '00:00:05', '00:00:06']
list2 = [2,3,4]
def create_stamp(d):
  s = '0'*(6-len(d))+d
  return ':'.join(s[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2))

def fill_stamps(a, b, fill_val = 0):
  original = dict(zip(a, b))
  max_v = int(''.join(re.findall('\d+', max(a, key=lambda x:int(''.join(re.findall('\d+', x)))))))
  return [original.get(create_stamp(str(i)), fill_val) for i in range(max_v+1)], [create_stamp(str(i)) for i in range(max_v+1)]

list4, list3 = fill_stamps(list1, list2)
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4]
['00:00:00', '00:00:01', '00:00:02', '00:00:03', '00:00:04', '00:00:05', '00:00:06']
```

Comment: 1) `'0'*(6-len(d))+d` is a poor man's `d.zfill(6)`. 2) Why define `fill_stamps` with `*args` if you're gonna unpack it into `a, b = args` in the very next line? Just make two parameters instead. 3) What the heck is that `max_v = ...` monstrosity? You can simplify that to `max_v = max(int(''.join(re.findall('\d+', x))) for x in a)`. One would think you would get _better_ at writing one-liners, but it looks like you're just making them more and more convoluted as time goes on?

Answer (score -1):

**Edit**: Fixed based on comments and post edits (using the term *fixed* rather loosely....)

I'm not going to lie and say this is the *best* way to do things, but maybe to help you think through the problem you can try this:

```
# Starting lists
list1 = ['00:00:02', '00:00:05', '00:00:06']
list2 = [2,3,4]
# create a list that looks like [2,5,6] from list1[]
list1_linker = []
for x in list1:
  list1_linker.append(int(x.split(":")[2]))
# Output lists
new_list1 = []
new_list2 = []
# Temp lists
temp_list1 = []
temp_list2 = []
# Build temps
for i in range(0,max(list1_linker)+1):
  temp_time_stamp = '00:00:'
  if i < 10:
    temp_time_stamp += '0'
    temp_time_stamp += str(i)
    temp_list1.append(temp_time_stamp)
  else:
    temp_time_stamp += str(i)
    temp_list1.append(temp_time_stamp)
  temp_list2.append(i)
# Build output 1
new_list1 = temp_list1
# Build output 2
for x in range(0,len(temp_list2)):
  if x in list1_linker:
    new_list2.append(list2.pop(0))
  else:
    new_list2.append(0)
# Print our lists    
print(new_list1)
print(new_list2)
```

Outputs:

```
['00:00:00', '00:00:01', '00:00:02', '00:00:03', '00:00:04', '00:00:05', '00:00:06']
[0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 4]
```

Now again, there are better ways to accomplish this, but based on the information in the question this should at least help you think about the problem

Comment: This doesn't match the desired output.

Comment: You're right (again)...... guess I am not understanding what the OP is asking for

Comment: Damn close though!

Comment: Can you help me understand the move from `list2 = [2,3,6] ` to `list4 = [0,0,2,0,0,3,6}`?

Comment: list4 just has a 0 for each place that did not have a value relating list2 to list3.

Comment: Your code incorrectly assumes that `list2[-1]` corresponds to the length of the output lists. That was just a coincidence, and it has been changed to a different number now to make that more obvious.

Comment: Yeah I did not understand the question fully at the time, fixing

Comment: Your code doesn't work correctly with time stamps above 1 minute.

Comment: Again while your technically correct (the best kind of correct?) I feel like this is getting a bit pedantic... the goal of my answer was not a bullet-proof solution to every case but rather a way for the OP to think about the problem in step by step fashion with beginner friendly syntax (`loop`s, `list`s, and `if`s)